# How do I assign discrete marker colors based on pandas DF column on plotly?

Tags: plotly

The scatterplot is plotting a column in dataframe which has either value 1 or 0. I want to be able to assign discrete color corresponding to each value **without** using a for loop(say mode=1 is blue marker, mode=0 is red marker). I am unable to find any examples/keywords in plotly.express.scatter() function. I keep getting a continuous color spectrum, which is not what I want.

I am trying to learn plotly, is what I'm trying to achieve possible? I know how do it in just matplotlib.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Plotly Express uses a continuous color scale for numerical data and a discrete color scale for string data, so if you convert your column to a string, you should get the expected outcome. Like this `df['column'] = df['column'].astype(str)` (in this case `df` is the data frame variable and `'column'` is likely `'mode'` given your screenshot above)

(Note that today there is a known bug wherein it doesn't read boolean columns correctly, so you'll have to convert those to strings also)

Comment: Oh ok, so no way then.

Comment: No, there is a way, just stringify your column :) I've edited my answer

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the type of the column to `category`:

in a notebook:

```py
%pylab inline
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

x_vals = linspace(0, 2 * pi, 21)
phases = linspace(0, pi / 2, 5)
data = {
    "x": np.hstack([x_vals for _ in range(len(phases))]),
    "y": sin(x_vals.reshape(1, -1) + phases.reshape(-1, 1)).flatten(),
    "phase": degrees(np.vstack([phases for _ in range(len(x_vals))]).T.flatten()),
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
px.scatter(df, x="x", y="y", color="phase")
```

yields the unwanted continuous color scale:
[image]

but a simple change to a category type for the desired column gives the desired results:

```py
df["phase"] = df["phase"].astype("category")
px.scatter(df, x="x", y="y", color="phase")
```

[image]